# Inserting a Button into HTML Cell

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I am currently trying to get this buttons into my HTML table.

This is the code I want to insert:

```
<button class=\"btn btn-primary btn-xs my-xs-btn\" type='button' onClick='changeRec(".$num.")' >
<span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-pencil\"></span> Edit
</button>
```

And here is my attempt at inserting it.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="myFunction()">Add</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
var row = table.insertRow(-1);
var cellInstruction = row.insertCell(-1);
cellInstruction.innerHTML = '<button class=\"btn btn-primary btn-xs my-xs-btn\" type='button' onClick='changeRec(".$num.")' >
                            <span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-pencil\"></span> Edit
                        </button>';
}
</script>
```

Comment: What is `cellInstruction` in your script?

Comment: Sorry, I missed a line of code when I was posting. cellInstruction is cell.

Comment: Now, what is `row` ?

Comment: I really messed up with transcribing the code. I have made the changes to the code, again. row is just the new row.

Answer (score 2):

You are not concatenating the string correctly and you do not need to escape double quotes.

Here is working example.

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" onclick="myFunction()">Add</button>
<table id="myTable"></table>
<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var cellInstruction = row.insertCell(-1);
    cellInstruction.innerHTML = '<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs my-xs-btn" type="button" onClick="changeRec(".$num.")" >'
    + '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit</button>';
  }
</script>
```

But you should rather separate your javascript from your html and use an eventlistener for the click event.

Here is how you could do that.

```js
var addBtn = document.getElementById('add-btn');

function addEditBtn() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var cellInstruction = row.insertCell(-1);
    cellInstruction.innerHTML = '<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs my-xs-btn" type="button">'
    + '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> Edit</button>';
}

addBtn.addEventListener('click', addEditBtn, false);
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="add-btn">Add</button>
<table id="myTable"></table>
```

An other way would be to create the button element using `document.createElement`.

```js
var addBtn = document.getElementById('add-btn');

function addEditBtn() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var cellInstruction = row.insertCell(-1);
    var button = document.createElement('button');
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    button.setAttribute('class', 'btn btn-primary btn-xs my-xs-btn');
    button.setAttribute('type', 'button');
    span.setAttribute('class', 'glyphicon glyphicon-pencil');
    span.innerHTML = " Edit";
    button.appendChild(span);
    cellInstruction.appendChild(button);
}

addBtn.addEventListener('click', addEditBtn, false);
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="add-btn">Add</button>
<table id="myTable"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

innerHTML only get/set value of an element which doesn't include the label itself

Answer (score 0):

I think, you messed somewhere in the brackets. I tested the below code using PHP and it works fine:

```
<?php
    $num = 4;
    $insert = "<button class='btn btn-primary btn-xs my-xs-btn' type='button' onClick='changeRec(".$num.")'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span> Edit</button>";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Row1 cell1</td>
    <td>Row1 cell2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row2 cell1</td>
    <td>Row2 cell2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row3 cell1</td>
    <td>Row3 cell2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(-1);

    cell1.innerHTML = "<?php echo $insert; ?>";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

```js
function myFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(-1);

    cell1.innerHTML = "<button class='btn btn-primary btn-xs my-xs-btn' type='button' onClick='changeRec()' ><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span> Edit</button>";

}
```

```css
table, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<body>

<p>Click the button to add a new row at the first position of the table and then add cells and content.</p>

<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Row1 cell1</td>
    <td>Row1 cell2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row2 cell1</td>
    <td>Row2 cell2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Row3 cell1</td>
    <td>Row3 cell2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```